# Find $a\in\mathbb{R}$ that guarantees there's a linear map $f$ s.t. $f(1,-1,1)=(2,a,-1),f(1,-1,2)=(a^2,-1,1),f(1,-1,-2)=(5,-1,-7)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I don't know how to tackle this exercise.

Clearly $V=\{(1,-1,1),(1,-1,2),(1,-1,-2)\}$ is a linearly dependent set, so we don't have $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined over a basis of its domain.  We're trying to solve $FB=A$ where $F$ is the matrix associated to the linear transformation, $B$ are the column vectors of $V$ and $A$ are the images of these vectors under $f$. But $B$ is noninvertible! So $F=AB^{-1}$ is a nonstarter.

We know $f(0,0,1)= f((1,-1,2)-(1,-1,1))=(a^2-2,-a-1,2)$. I can try to find other images, but I feel like I'm not being methodical enough and that I'm missing the "central idea" of this exercise.

**Help!**

**Update:** with the help of the comments I then did the following

$$(a^2,-1,1)=f(1,-1,2)=f\bigg(4/3(1,-1,1)-1/3(1,-1,-2)\bigg)  \ \ \\ \stackrel{f \text{ is linear}}{=} 4/3f(1,-1,1)- 1/3f(1,-1,-2)= (1,4/3a+1/3,1) \iff \\ a=-1$$

How can I justify that this is a sufficient condition for $f$ to exist?

Comment: $4(1,-1,1)-3(1,-1,2)=(1,-1,-2)$; linear map must preserve that

Comment: Is it sufficient if I prove that (i) $(1,-1,1)$ is a linear combination of $(1,-1,2)$ and $(1,-1,-2)$, e.g. $(1,-1,1)=\alpha (1,-1,2)+ \beta (1,-1,-2)$, and thar (ii) for certain $a \in \mathbb{R}, f(1,-1,1)= \alpha f(1,-1,2) + \beta f(1,-1,-2)$?

Comment: Yes, that should work

Answer (score 1):

We have $4(1,-1,1)-3(1,-1,2)=(1,-1,-2)$,

so by linearity $4f(1,-1,1)-3f(1,-1,2)=f(1,-1,-2)$;

i.e., $4(2,a,-1)-3(a^2,-1,1)=(5,-1,-7)$,

so $(8-3a^2,4a+3,-7)=(5,-1,-7)$,

so $a=-1.$